# Mapa Leafletjs API se queda en gris

Tags: javascript, api, leafletjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo Javascript:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Y un simple div con id "mapa"

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

En la documentación de leafletjs (https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) dice que con solo eso ya podemos visualizar un ejemplo de mapa sencillo, pero al momento de abrir la web me sale completamente en gris, de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco su ayuda y comentarios, es primera vez que uso la API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pero es que te falta añadir la capa de imágenes del mapa (los tiles)!! Esto es el código que pone la misma documentación

```
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

Ejemplo

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map { height: 180px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>


 <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>
     
<div id="map"></div>
```